# "clear" command in GNOME terminal returns "terminals database is inaccessible"

Tags: 14.04, gnome-terminal

I am currently running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Out of nowhere, my 3.6.2 GNOME terminal is returning "`terminals database is inaccessible`" when the "`clear`" command is executed. Any suggestions on how I can troubleshoot this problem?

Thanks for the help,

Eric

Comment: Wild guess: what does `dpkg -V ncurses-base ncurses-term` return?

Comment: Thanks for the reply steeldriver. "dpkg -V ncurses-base ncurses-term" returns nothing.

Comment: did this help? http://superuser.com/questions/319912/i-cant-clear-the-terminal-in-mac-os-x-lion-terminals-database-is-inaccessibl

Comment: Do you happen to use conda? I had the same issue and found the solution here. https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/994

Comment: Hello Dilmurat, I think you are correct. I do use conda and removing conda bin from my path resolves the "terminals database is inaccessible" error. I will pursue the solution in the link you provided. Thank you!

Answer (score 10):

This can happen a lot with terminal multiplexers (screen, tmux, etc...)

If if you are running one of those, make sure that your TERM is set to `screen-256color` for the broadest support.  I've run into issues in BSD, Linux, Multiple x window managers, etc... from this.

Check for `set -g default-terminal screen-256color` in `~/.tmux.conf` or `term    screen-256color` in `~/.screenrc` as TERM is changed by your multiplexer when you load it.

If `echo $TERM` already says `screen-256color` try this:

`TERM='xterm' clear`.  If that works, then your terminal emulator doesn't support the standard multiplexer configuration.  You might need to add something special for that particular terminal emulator in your bashrc/bash_profile.

Keep in mind that this problem is related to your tool selection and configuration.  Ubuntu attempts to choose defaults that work well with other defaults so that everything 'just works'.

Comment: I was able to solve the problem by just commenting out this line in my tmux conf (which was the example conf shipped with tmux):
`#set -g default-terminal "tmux-256color"`

Comment: After you update your `.tmux.conf`, you can use `tmux kill-server` to force a reload of the configuration.

Answer (score 0):

Open the hidden `~/.bashrc` bash customization file, see if the `clear` command is being overridden with something else, then comment it with an hash at the start of the line, close the terminal and restart, or type in `. ~/.bashrc` to refresh the bashrc script immediately.

Also both the commands `env` and `set` will give you information about the environment variables of your OS, you can start troubleshooting there.

Comment: just run alias to see a list of aliases

Comment: Hello Amias. I was unaware of this usage of the alias command. Thank you for the suggestion.

Comment: Hello uncanny_valley. There was no alias interfering with my usage of the clear command. Thank you for the troubleshooting suggestion. As it turns out, user Dilmurat was correct in assuming that my conda installation has an ncurses issue that was interfering with my usage of the clear command.

Comment: @EricSmoll No problem, glad you managed to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Either your `$TERM` variable is not right or your `TERMCAP` db is corrupted.

This message occurs when your terminal type cannot be matched in the `TERMCAP` database.

the termcap database on ubuntu 16.04 is in `/lib/terminfo` , not sure if its the same on 14.04 , there must be an file in that tree of the same name as the value in your `$TERM`.

the `ncurses-base` package manages this , check if its installed.