# clear command - terminals database is inaccessible

Tags: 16.04, command-line

I am using Ubuntu 16.04. When I use the `clear` command in a terminal, it produces this error:

```
terminals database is inaccessible
```

But when I use `sudo clear` it works as intended.

I have removed some files in `/var/www/` and, after that, this problem started. I checked this question ["clear" command in GNOME terminal returns "terminals database is inaccessible"](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808549/clear-command-in-gnome-terminal-returns-terminals-database-is-inaccessible) but that did not help in any way

Here is the output of `strace -etrace=open clear`:

```
open("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/tls/x86_64/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/tls/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/x86_64/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libncursesw.so.5", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/home/user/anaconda3/bin/../lib/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = -1 ENOENT (No such file or directory)
open("/etc/ld.so.cache", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
open("/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6", O_RDONLY|O_CLOEXEC) = 3
terminals database is inaccessible
+++ exited with 1 +++
```

Comment: Hmm... have you messed with how the linker resolves dynamic dependencies (such as setting `LD_RUN_PATH` or `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` or similar)? what is the output of `printenv | grep LIB`?

Comment: @steeldriver anaconda3 is interfering with the clear command.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Path for Anaconda3 is set in `.bashrc`. It is interfering with the `clear` command.
Removing Anaconda path from path solved the issue.

Here is the GitHub reference for the issue: https://github.com/ContinuumIO/anaconda-issues/issues/331

Answer (score 3):

You might have moved the `anaconda` directory **after** installation and some bash script links in some files from `anaconda` directory are still pointing to the previous location. Simplest solution is to delete your current `anaconda` installation directory, remove any paths in `.bashrc` pointing to it and reinstall it in the desired location.

Comment: How does this differ from the other answer?

Comment: Not necessarily, seems like the installation of Anaconda has conflicts with `clear` command...

Answer (score 2):

This is an issue you'll face after moving the Anaconda Python directory to a different location.
In your $PATH variable, you will your Python home's bin directory ($PYTHON_HOME/bin). Just go this bin directory, rename the existing "clear" binary file and login again.

```
cd $PYTHON_HOME/bin
mv clear clear.bkup
```

Answer (score 2):

```
export TERMINFO=/usr/share/terminfo
```

this works for me.

Comment: This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 0):

In case you see *"(your_env_name)"* to the left, typing`conda deactivate` will solve your problem

Answer (score 0):

I just edited my `.bashrc` file (if you use another type of shell, you should edit the respective `.*rc` file).

I just added this line in the end, so that it runs every time I open a new terminal:

```
conda deactivate
```

Once I found that this command solves my problem, putting it to run every time I open a terminal is an easy solution.

Answer (score 0):

```
sudo mv $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/clear $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/clear_old
This Worked for me on Ubuntu 20.04 too. Thanks
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this by replacing conda clear with the system clear.

1. find the system clear command path by typing `which clear`, copy the results;
2. replace by `mv PATH_TO_SYSTEM_CLEAR $CONDA_PREFIX/bin/clear`.

Answer (score 0):

This did work to me:

```
alias clear="TERM=xterm /usr/bin/clear"
```

Add it to the `.bashrc` file.