# Clear needs root access

Tags: command-line, 18.04, xterm

Bit of a newbie here, but couldn't find this problem anywhere on the forums.
Running Ubuntu 18.04, default terminal.

Upon entering the `clear` command, terminal returned

> terminals database is inaccessible

Only help I found online was to check the `TERM` environment variable which was set to `xterm-256color`

However, I tried `sudo clear` and this seems to work. Don't understand what's happening. Any fix suggestions would be appreciated.

EDIT : The issue persists with different terminal emulators and even on CLI. Still haven't found a fix.

Answer (score 0):

Try installing the italic terminfo:

```
tic resources/xterm-256color-italic.terminfo
tic resources/tmux-256color-italic.terminfo
```

Source: [terminals database is inaccessible #33](https://github.com/nicknisi/dotfiles/issues/33)

See also: [clear command - terminals database is inaccessible](https://askubuntu.com/questions/988694)

See also: [“clear” command in GNOME terminal returns “terminals database is inaccessible”](https://askubuntu.com/questions/808549)

Comment: Have gone through these. None of the solutions seem to work.